# Angularjs Routeprovider in MODx subfolder

Tags: angularjs, modx, ngroute, route-provider, angularjs-ng-route

I've got angularjs app running on MODx website. There is some page with URL like

*localhost/www.mysite.com/angularapp/*

which contains the app.

URLs inside app look like

*localhost/www.mysite.com/angularapp/category/1*

base href is set to /www.mysite.com/angularapp/

Everything works fine, but I can not reach the subpages of the app directly.

If I type *localhost/www.mysite.com/angularapp/category/1* in address bar, I get to modx start page. But if I go to the link via app - it works.

What did I miss ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to exclude the angularapp folder from the default htaccess friendly URL rewrite and add a new rule for this. Include the following line

```
RewriteRule ^(angularapp/)(.*)$ index.php?q=$1&r=$2 [L,QSA]
```

before the friendly URL part. The angular app has to work with $_GET['r'] then.

```
# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Edit: changed the htaccess code to the final solution.

Comment: That's sound good. But the angular app is defined inside modx template... /angularapp/ is one of the modx resources. If I exclude it, i get 404...

Comment: If all happens in MODX (the route angularapp/ the only resource running the app code), you have multiple options. One could be building a own rewrite rule before the friendly URL part: RewriteRule ^(angularapp/)(.*)$ index.php?q=$1&r=$2 [L,QSA] The angular app has to work with $_GET['r'] then. Another one could be the customRequest extra, that could do an own routing to multiple request parameters for the app.

Comment: I think RewriteRule  ^angularapp/. /www.mysite.com/angularapp/$1 [L] did it ) Your rewriterule works too. Will stick with it, as it's more versatile

Comment: Your rule makes no sense. It rewrites urls starting with angularapp/ plus one sign to your domain plus angularapp/ with no path after ($1 is never filled).